# how do i set custom axis ticks on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am attempting to set the x axis ticks by months past in my graph.

i have tried:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(30))
```

but that half works by showing the number of days every thirty days.
i have also tried:

```
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(my_data), step=30))
ticklist = []
for i in range(len(my_data)):
    if i % 30 == 0:
        ticklist.append(int(i / 30))
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(ticklist)), ticklist)
```

this ends up showing the month numbers but they are assigned to the x axis values of the month number (the number 5 month is on the fifth value of the graph not the 150th).

i want the result to be that there is an ascending list of numbers (month numbers) along every 30th value on the graph. this is to show the time span of the data by months.

Comment: What does your data look like? Is your x-data formatted as floats, ints or datetime object? Are you plotting lists, numpy arrays, pd Dataframes, ... ?

Comment: Indeed, it will depend **entirely** on what kind of input data you have. No such information is given in the question. See [mvce].